# Reverse the stack order of floated elements

Tags: html, css

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqbu2d70/

Requirements:

- In responsive mode, the bottom box must be at the bottom, middle in the middle, top at the top
- In desktop mode, the bottom box must be on the left side
- No javascript
- The height of the parent must be the height of the biggest child (so no absolute positioning)

You can see that as the fiddle stands now, the bottom is staying at the top as you reduce the width of the window.  How can the above be achieved with just HTML / CSS?

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.random-height {
  height: 200px !important;
}
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .child {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child random-height">bottom</div>
  <div class="child">middle</div>
  <div class="child">top</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what flexbox is for. What're your browser support requirements?

Comment: No need for flexbox here, just the old fashioned `float` will do the trick

Comment: My answer does exactly what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by applying the following to both the parent and the children, but it seems...... *wrong*?   https://jsfiddle.net/pqbu2d70/1/

```
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
```

Comment: You are also switching the position of top. all you have done is completely rotate them not place bottom at the bottom.

Comment: I dont know, I honestly haven't seen this approach before. I would just use `float`. I have added an answer that just uses float;

Comment: @DCdaz that's what I wanted - top at the top, middle in the middle, bottom at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry Rob thats not stated in your Q you only mention Moving bottom down.

Comment: @DCdaz no worries, I thought it was self-explanatory.  Just updated.

Comment: Ive updated my answer for the complete flip. also this will be a little more compatble than your transform for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet would be using `direction`. Change it in the parent to `rtl` (right to left), and in the children reset it to `initial`.

In order for it to work, instead of floating, you would need to set the children as `inline-block` elements.

I haven't solved every margin/padding issue, but it would be something like this:

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pqbu2d70/2/)

```css
.parent {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
}

.random-height{
    height: 200px !important;
    
}

.child {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    direction: initial;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {

    .child {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">top</div>
    <div class="child">middle</div>
    <div class="child random-height">bottom</div>
</div>
```